# Installing ATI drivers on a Switchable Graphics Laptop

Tags: drivers, installation, bios, amd-catalyst

I recently re-installed Windows 7 and downloaded all the necessary updates, but it never updates my ATI drivers to the latest version.

I had to do it manually by uninstalling the current version and then installing the new one, but every time I try that the installation fails. I spent some time to figure out why but couldn't find a reason until I noticed that my laptop is now defaulting to the Intel card, so I figured that maybe the driver installation couldn't find the ATI card.

How can I switch to the ATI card without the Catalyst software, assuming that this is the problem? My BIOS doesn't have the ability to switch between graphics cards, and I can't find my ATI card in Device Manager.

My computer is an HP Pavilion dv6 with both AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5650 and Intel HD Graphics.

Comment: @Sickest Yes right i'm sorry my bad.

Comment: If you got the ATI driver directly from ATI/AMD, then it may not install du eto it being the 'generic' driver.  Go get the latest version offered by the Notebook manufacture (HP) and try those.

Comment: To expand what techie007 said, you need to figure out the exact laptop model, and then search it in the official [HP support site](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/drivers.html).